# Thursday morning open interest data for newly listed weekly options

Tags: options, interest

The open interest data is available for the newly listed weekly options during the market hours on Thursdays. Yet the open interest data supposedly gets updated once per day after the market close. Where does the Thursday morning OI data for the newly listed weeklies then come from?